# Reverse LIKE %...% possible?

Tags: mysql

In short I want to match a dictionary entry to a row of text, but it doesn't have to match the whole row, just the beginning. So it's in effect a sort of reverse LIKE %...%

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE
    (`simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于2000多年'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于2000多'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于2000'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于200'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于20'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于2'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久，'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠久'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常悠'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非常'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史非'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历史'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的历'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔的'
    OR `simplified` = '铅笔'
    OR `simplified` = '铅')
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`simplified`) DESC;
```

This works and does what I need but I know it's grossly inefficient. Is there any other way of doing it? Help much appreciated!!

Example results:

```
97576   铅笔
97484   铅
97566   铅
```

Comment: nice pattern generated :P

Comment: 'text%' wouldn't work because it would match anything with a row of 'text', 'text1', 'text12' etc. But infact I want to find any rows that match the string above completely from the first character up to any in the series

Comment: @DominicEngland which "string above" ? You're matching against 20 possible strings as it is now.

Comment: @nos stop, read, think :)

Comment: @nos there's one string, he wants to match any row in the DB which is a *prefix* of that string, so he manually expanded out the query to list all nonempty prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
WHERE `simplified` = SUBSTRING(
  '铅笔的历史非常悠久，它起源于2000多年',
  0, CHAR_LENGTH(`simplified`))
```

? Probably not indexable, but at least the query is short. :)

And you can probably optimize it by adding

```
AND `simplified` LIKE '铅%'
```

to reject all the rows that don't at least start with the right character.

Comment: Hi cheers, yeah that's in effect what I'm doing, the max length `simplified` is 20, which is the length of the query. Although adding the "AND `simplified` LIKE '铅%'" isn't a bad idea, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE simplified like '铅%'
```

Comment: I think it's implied by the OPs question that they want to match the longest string as quickly as possible, which this won't do.

Comment: @Ben:- The string is complicated and it is difficult to fetch the longest one. I guess this would work!

Comment: Yeah no it won't I'm afraid, that would match any result starting with  铅 and would pull back lots of none matching entries

Comment: This will match any string that starts with 铅. That is not what the OP asked for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `REGEXP` to match the field to a regular expression.

[Official Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)